# Read lines from file and run external program with arguments (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, foreach

I'm trying to read line by line from a file containing 5 filenames (1 in each line).
I want then start an external application with an argument containing this line and write the output to a text file .
Unfortunately it only process 3 of 5 files, any idea why?

Thanks in advance!

My current code looks like this:

```
ForEach ($line in (Get-Content "C:\temp\filenames.txt")) 
    {
    Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/c img_stat.exe', $line ,'>> c:\temp\files.txt'
    }

    Remove-Item -Path C:\temp\filenames.txt
```

Comment: What does the following result in?

Get-Content "C:\temp\filenames.txt" | Measure-Object

Comment: Count    : 5
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :

Comment: Maybe it's related to img_stat.exe try adding -wait to start-process

Comment: Already tried that but the result is the same. 
I have to run the process in a loop because img_stat.exe doesn't support multiple filenames as an argument.

Comment: Is it starting 5 instances?

Comment: @DavidMartin @Agent47 : My guess here is a race condition on `>> c:\temp\files.txt` as each process is somehow launch in parallel. I suggest to output each line with `>> c:\temp\files_[line number].txt`.

Comment: I added a sleep timer, seems like it's working now.

Comment: @agent47 A sleep timer is somehow ok with short delay processes which output only few lines. I'll suggest you anyway to isolate each process output for safety considerations.

Comment: Don't know how to do that, any hint? Sleep timer works for now, as i only get a few lines from the process, it's nothing big.